# What is the relationship between the structure/composition of the medium and the speed of light in this medium?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, electromagnetic-radiation, solid-state-physics, quantum-electrodynamics

We kwon that the speed of light (C=Co/n) depends on the properties of the medium in which it propagates (n, index of refraction).

As n is characteristics of the environment in which light propagates, in other words we could say from spectroscopy that it is a function of the Physicochemical properties of substance. We could include here, the chemical composition, as well as the spatial distribution of these atoms or elements, and other thermodynamic parameters such as temperature, pressure , …., etc.

Would it be possible to attribute a structure and composition to the vacuum knowing that n for the vacuum equals 1?
Would it be possible to proceed in reverse?

Comment: VTC as unclear as what the question is.

Answer (score 2):

The speed of light is related to two properties, the [permittivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permittivity) $\varepsilon$ and the [permeability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permeability_(electromagnetism)) $\mu$, by the equation:

$$ v = \frac{c}{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\varepsilon \mu}} $$

In a dielectric material like glass the permittivity and permeability can in principle be calculated from the electronic structure of the material, though in practice the calculation may be too hard to do with any great accuracy. In this sense the speed of light is indeed related to the properties of the dielectric as you suggest.

However we cannot start with the speed of light and use it to tell us very much about the properties of the dielectric. The speed of light is just one number, and the electronic properties of the dielectric will in general be fiendishly complicated.

The permittivity and permeability of a dielectric are basically due to the electrons present in that dielectric and the quantum states those electrons occupy. But if we remove all the electrons (and the nuclei they orbit), so we are left with a vacuum, the permittivity and permeability do not disappeaer. Instead they become the vacuum permittivity $\varepsilon_0$ and the vacuum permeability $\mu_0$, and the speed of light is then just:

$$ c = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\varepsilon_0 \mu_0}} $$

and your question is whether the values of $\varepsilon_0$ and $\mu_0$ tell us anything about the structure of the vacuum.

But we run into the same problem as when we were considering the properties of a dielectric. The [electromagnetic vacuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QED_vacuum) is described by quantum electrodynamics, and in principle we can use quantum electrodynamics to calculate the vacuum permittivity and permeability. So in this sense the speed of light in vacuum is related to the structure of the vacuum.

The problem is that, as before, the QED vacuum is very complicated and the speed of light is just one number. So while we can calculate the speed of light if we know the properties of the QED vacuum,  we can't go the other way i.e. start with the speed of light and calculate the properties of the vacuum from it.